# How to read cuda binary code

Tags: assembly, cuda

Cuda generates 'cubin': cuda binary. This can be converted to assembly by running cuobjdump or nvdisasm (see also http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html).

Now I have this wonderful assembly code and I have no proper way of reading it. Are there tools that

1. place the assembly next to the source
2. that explain the operations (like 'DMUL R4, R8, R2;' which is obviously a multiplication, but also something I don't know, like
   'IMAD.HI.X')
3. keep track of register count (I'm using cuda toolkit 5.5, I know that the tools spit out some counter as of version 6.5 or something)?

And is there something like a tutorial? It seems like almost nobody is reading cubins as googling results in hardly any results.

Comment: [This question is considered off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @musefan: 
if 
    the question is about "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"
then
   it's proper to ask here. I am not sure then why it isn't?

Comment: that is referring to if the question is about a *specific* software tool. For example: "How can I create a new project in Visual Studio 2010?". But asking to recommend tools is off topic. Perhaps you might want to check out [softwarerecs.se] and see if the question is better suited over there

Comment: Asking for a tutorial is explicitly off topic.  You can read that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).    SASS is the GPU assembly code and it is somewhat documented in the link you gave in your question (i.e. [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#instruction-set-ref)).  My suggestion is to learn about PTX by studying the documentation [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#abstract).  Many questions about SASS are answered in the PTX documentation.

Comment: I understand I shouldn't kick-start a discussion and therefor ask for opinions about a well-debated subject. In this case however, I don't think there have been discussions and therefor the reason why asking for tutorials are off-topic seem not to apply. Same goes for asking which tool to use. I don't think there will be spam by software vendors?

And thanks for the hint about PTX, will read that.

Answer (score 2):

1. nvdisasm --print-line-info, see http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#nvdisasm-options
2. See http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#instruction-set-ref
3. - nvcc -v, see http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-guiding-compiler-driver
   - nvdisasm --print-life-ranges, see http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#nvdisasm-options

Comment: This only works versions newer than 5.5. Still will help others though :)